# Publish Customization: Cannot merge documents; Duplicate object is found: Validation failed

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have created four custom unbound (non-persisted) fields in my custom DAC:

This is my dac:

```
    #region Descr
    [PXString(256, InputMask = "")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Descripcion")]
    [PXFormula(typeof(Selector<InventoryItemInventoryItem.inventorySecID, InventoryItem.descr>))] 
    public virtual string Descr { get; set; }
    public abstract class descr : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<descr> { }
    #endregion
  
    
    #region UsrDivision
    [PXString(25, InputMask = "")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Division")]
    [INDivision.List()]
    [PXFormula(typeof(Selector<InventoryItemInventoryItem.inventorySecID, InventoryItemExt.usrDivision>))] 
    public virtual string UsrDivision { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrDivision : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<usrDivision> { }
    #endregion
  
    #region UsrGrupo
    [PXString(25, InputMask = "")]
    [INGrupo.List()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Grupo")]
    [PXFormula(typeof(Selector<InventoryItemInventoryItem.inventorySecID, InventoryItemExt.usrGrupo>))] 
    public virtual string UsrGrupo { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrGrupo : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<usrGrupo> { }
    #endregion 
    
    
    #region ItemClassID
    [PXInt()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Sub Grupo", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
    [PXDimensionSelector(INItemClass.Dimension, typeof(Search<INItemClass.itemClassID>), typeof(INItemClass.itemClassCD), DescriptionField = typeof(INItemClass.descr),
     CacheGlobal = true)]
    [PXFormula(typeof(Selector<InventoryItemInventoryItem.inventorySecID, InventoryItem.itemClassID>))] 
    public virtual int? ItemClassID { get; set; }
    public abstract class itemClassID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<itemClassID> { }
    #endregion
```

I added those custom fields to my grid but at the moment of publishing my project I get that error:

```
Compiled projects: DesarrollosQP,DesarrolloQPKardex,FieldsQP,BigCommerceConnector2019r2,CloudInfoFE,HotFixInvoiceAndCP
Cannot merge documents; Duplicate object is found: AUFields#IN202500
```

See the screenshot below:

[image]

This is my customization projects screen:

[image]

Can you help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your customization project list, there are three additional projects which touch the screen IN202500.  To learn which project causes the conflict, you can un-publish the projects.  Next, publish the projects one at a time until you determine which project causes the conflict.  For example, it's possible a GI which shares the same sitemap entry.  OR some UI controls cannot be merged in certain parts of the customized webpage.

For those three projects, I recommend to include a Level identifier to establish the publish order.  This step might help with the conflict error.

Here is the link which describes what happens in Acumatica, while publishing multiple customizations in a site.
[Simultaneous Use of Multiple Customizations](https://help-2020r1.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=1c134c6b-5135-413c-980f-da66722b53f2)

Comment: Thanks @Chris H, It was very useful, I assigned a level for each of my projects and it solved the issue, thanks again.